# How to relate two classes together when some shared code is auto-generated in both?

Tags: c#, class, oop, inheritance

I have two classes that I would like to share code between. These classes represent screens in my app, and both inherit from a base screen class. The first class (`MyList`) already exists, and encapsulates most of the behavior that I want to perform. The second class (`MyNewList`) needs only to slightly tweak the behavior in the first class.

Normally, I would have MyNewList inherit from MyList and be done with it. But, in this case, both classes have common code which is auto-generated into those classes. This code causes loads of warnings because MyNewList is hiding MyList members without using `new` or `override`.

To make things even stickier, some of that code could be shared 100% (exact same fields), and the rest needs to be unique to each class.

To make matters more difficult, the code generator cannot be modified to change the output. I also cannot trigger the code generation into a separate abstract base class, which would allow both classes to inherit from the common base.

The two classes represent different custom implementations. It is possible to simply use the first class and add some branching logic to perform the behavior that MyNewList wants (and eliminate MyNewList). However, my lead developer would like it to be a separate class. I understand that desire - it's cleaner if we can use inheritance, but I don't see a solution here.

Below is my code, attempting to use inheritance:

```
public class MyList : ScreenBase
{
    protected override void PageLoad()
    {
        base.PageLoad();

        //Do page loading type stuff
    }

    protected override void PageRefresh()
    {
        base.PageRefresh();

        //Do page refreshing type stuff
    }

    protected override void PageClose()
    {
        base.PageClose();

        CloseThePage(RESULT_CLOSE);
    }

    #region Auto-generated code

    public const string RESULT_LOAD = "Load";
    public const string RESULT_BACK = "Back";
    public const string RESULT_CLOSE = "Close";

    public string Property_Date
    {
        get { /*get date from somewhere*/ }
        set { /*assign date to somewhere*/ }
    }

    public void CloseThePage(string result)
    {
        //Route to next location based on result
    }

    #endregion
}
```

Second screen:

```
public class MyNewList : MyList
{
    protected override void PageLoad()
    {
        base.PageLoad();

        //Do additonal page loading behavior
    }

    //allow the rest of the base behavior to take over

    #region Auto-generated code

    public const string RESULT_LOAD = "Load";
    public const string RESULT_BACK = "Back";
    public const string RESULT_CLOSE = "Close";

    public string Property_Date
    {
        get { /*get date from somewhere*/ }
        set { /*assign date to somewhere*/ }
    }

    public void CloseThePage(string result)
    {
        //Completely different routing behavior here
    }

    #endregion
}
```

Everything inside of the `#region Auto-generated code` region shows hiding warnings with this approach.

**How can I reuse `MyList`'s event code from inside of `MyNewList`?**

Comment: Please describe your problem better,  Chances are you solution is architected wrong, but you're trying to have someone solve your problem using the architecture you've provided them.  It sound like you just want to use an interface, and work with the interface instead of the concrete implementations.

Comment: @johnny5 You are correct - the architecture (specifically the limitations imposed by the auto-generated code) is definitely the problem. I am asking someone to help me solve the problem inside of that constraint.

Comment: @johnny5 I attempted to explain it as clearly as possible. Do you have specific questions or aspects that you are confused about?

Comment: If you're deadset on using this auto-generated code, you could wrap that part inside a private static class, but that seems just as bad as whatever you're trying to avoid.

Comment: The you can't modify the code generation is the real sticking point.  What can you modify, can't you just make your classes partial and say that they inherit from an interface and let the auto generated code satisfy the conditions

Comment: @johnny5 I can modify everything outside of the #region in my code. I will think about your idea for a bit. Thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: I think what you need is a sort of "decorator", you need to decorate the "MyList " class with "MyNewList", basically inherit and take "MyList" as parameter in your constructor.